# Static resources not loading on GitHub Pages

Tags: redirect, github, github-pages

I have created a website and am trying to host it on git hub pages. My site is available at -

```
http://<username>.github.io/<project name>/
```

But the static files for my site are available at the following path -

```
http://<username>.github.io/css/site.css
http://<username>.github.io/script/main.js
```

The above path omits the `<project name>`

So whenever I hit the url my static files are not loaded.

Is there a way to make it work with the github url?

**Note:** When I use a custom domain everything works fine because the relative paths are fine in that case.

**Temporary Solution**
I have created a [User page instead of a Project page](https://help.github.com/articles/user-organization-and-project-pages) to overcome this issue.

Comment: does a website exist at `username.github.io` too? what happens when you go to `username.github.io/css/site.css` in the browser? you might have to try `raw.username.github.io/css/site.css`

Comment: No there is no website at username.github.io, css file ate not available at that location. What is 'raw'?

Comment: you need to change the static urls for your css and scripts to point to the right location then. just try `/css/site.css`

Comment: Yes but then it would not work with actual domain.

Comment: you cannot have it both ways, either create the username.github.io site and put the style there or put it in the project so style would be at username.github.io/projectname/css/site.css

Comment: `raw.github.com` is the subdomain used by GitHub to show you the "raw" version of your files in the repo, meaning just the pure file, outside of the website structure. Open a file in your repo and click "Raw" in the toolbar on the top right corner to check it out.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From the [documentation to setup a custom domain](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-up-a-custom-domain-with-pages):

> Warning: Project pages subpaths like
>   http://username.github.io/projectname will not be redirected to a
>   project's custom domain.

This means that due to the relative paths you can either have the assets on your `username.github.io/project-name` **or** on your custom domain.

If you want them in the github one check what the documentation says about the [`baseurl`](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/github-pages/) configuration, it's at the bottom of the page, in the "Project Url Structure". It's simple you just need to add a

```
baseurl: /project-name
```

row to your `_config.yml` and use the `{{ baseurl }}` tag in your permalinks, jekyll will do the substitutions. And to test it locally just run the server with this option

```
jekyll serve --baseurl ''
```

Hope it helps :) Happy coding!

Comment: I think the permalink tag should be `{{ site.baseurl }}` instead of `{{ baseurl }}`

Comment: FWIW, I had the same problem while using webpack to build my site. In `webpack.config.js` set [`output.publicPath`](https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/configuration#outputpublicpath)`: /project-name`. Even so, the basic principal of setting the published url path in the build config is the correct solution.

Answer (score 38):

The other option is to include the file `.nojekyll` in your top-level directory which tells github to just serve your pages with out trying to break them (this is useful if you are trying to post the oputput from sphinx which does not need any more parsing/munging/rewriting).

[relevant link](http://amitsaha.github.io/site/notes/articles/sphinx/static_html.html)

Comment: I was tearing my hair out over this! A simple 2 file site (`index.html` and `_bundle.js`) needed the `.nojekyll` file to work.

Answer (score 1):

If your project is a React app created with [Create React App](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app), set the `homepage` in your `package.json`, for example:

```json
"homepage": "/<project name>",
```

If you're not using client-side routing, use this:

```json
"homepage": ".",
```

See https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#building-for-relative-paths.