# How to avoid having to change site.baseurl -> site.github.url between master/gh-pages?

Tags: git, github, jekyll

I'm using github to host my [blog](https://mbigras.github.io/) built with jekyll.

I read in [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18023908/static-resources-not-loading-on-git-hub-pages) and the [documentation](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/github-pages/) that I need to change `site.baseurl` to `site.github.url` to get my static resources to be served. So that's what I did and now everything is working. See diff below between `master` and `gh-pages`:

[image]

It wasn't too much of a pain to do, I just project-wide replaced using atom; however, I'm wondering, is there a better workaround? Ideally I'd like my workflow to be so I can just work on my blog using a [normal branching model](https://www.google.com/search?q=a+successful+git+branching+model&oq=a+succes&aqs=chrome.0.0j69i60l2j69i57j0l2.1526j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) and then merge with `gh-pages` as if it's a release branch and not have to worry about making the search and replace every time.

Thanks for your help :)

Edit: So strange, I just merged `master` with `gh-pages` and it seems like git just automagically handled the whole thing for me. So different question. Does git really know not to change `site.github.url` to `site.baseurl` when I make the merge? How does that work?

Comment: Git merges changes. So if you have changed the url on the `gh-pages` branch, but never touch it on the `master` branch, changes you merge in from `master` onto `gh-pages` will not include a change of the url, so the url used on `gh-pages` will stay the way it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using `jekyll.environment`:

```
{% if jekyll.environment == "production" %}
  <a class="post-link" href="{{ post.url | prepend: site.github.url }}">{{ post.title }}</a>
{% else %}
  <a class="post-link" href="{{ post.url | prepend: site.baseurl }}">{{ post.title }}</a>
{% endif %}
```

In your build command you then have to set `JEKYLL_ENV=production` . This is done automatically by GitHub. For other platforms, you may have to do this manually (in a *Rakefile* for example):

```
JEKYLL_ENV=production jekyll build
```

By default, `JEKYLL_ENV` equals `development`.

Comment: Do you think github handled it for me automatically? Please see my edit

Answer (score 4):

[As of Jekyll 3.3](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/pull/5580#issuecomment-260630148), if you're using the latest version of the [`github-pages` gem](https://github.com/github/pages-gem), you can now just use `site.url` everywhere. In development it will automatically be set to localhost and in production it will be set to your appropriate Github URL.

Comment: which was quite an unfortunate decision, as many development environments won't have url set to localhost (e.g. those working in VMs)

Answer (score 0):

1. You can leave `baseurl` empty (`baseurl: ""`) in your `_config.yml`.
2. In this case, you don't need to prepend `baseurl` to `post_url`

There has been some confusion around baseurl and url, you might want to read this clarification by Jekyll's maintainer:
https://byparker.com/blog/2014/clearing-up-confusion-around-baseurl/

```
site.url: https://domain.com # your domain
site.baseurl: "/blog" # the path to your website (optionnal)
site.github.url: https://username.github.io # your GitHub URL
```

Comment: I don't understand __"You don't need to prepend anything to post_url"__ You always need `baseurl` for any link to post or assets.

Comment: I meant, in this case, when `baseurl` is empty.