# Github Pages doesn't load all files

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-devtools, github-pages

I'm building a website as part of a uni project.
The main folder with its subfolders and files show up on the GitHub repository but when I access the web page and check the sources on the Chrome Developer Tools some files are missing..

GitHub Repository:

[image: GitHub Repository]

Chrome Dev Tools Sources:

[image: Chrome Dev Tools Sources]

Not sure how to address this issue :/

Comment: Chrome only shows the files that are downloaded, could it be the other files aren't used?

Comment: I'm using it in my main html tho.. `<script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/emoji-picker-textarea/index.js"></script>` and get a 404

Comment: This question has just got an answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18023908/static-resources-not-loading-on-github-pages